# Tratamento de encoding em XML

Tags: php, xml

Estou tentando fazer um request para uma URL que contem um retorno em `XML` com a função `simplexml_load_file('url')` e só recebo `false`quando faço o debug usando `var_dump`.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.cinemark.com.br/programacao.xml');

var_dump($xml);
```

Retorno:

```
bool(false)
```

Qual outro método posso usar para tratar `XML` fora esta função, e qual seria a aplicação "correta" para esta função?

Após ativar a exibição de erros no php, recebo o seguinte warning:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://www.cinemark.com.br/programacao.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): � ...

Acredito que seja algum problema de encoding, já tentei colocar  a função `header()` e usar o `chatset=utf-8` porém o erro é este apresentado acima.

Após utilizar o `mb_detect_encoding` recebo: "UTF-8"

Comment: coloquei o `header` como `iso-8859-1`, e fiz o request com `file_get_contents` e depois `simplexml_load_string` com o resultado do `file_get_contents` e o erro é o mesmo só que com o caracter diferente " ï¿½"

Comment: consegue elaborar uma resposta?

Comment: Recomendei como teste apenas, provavelmente para uso definitivo seja melhor outra solução. Quem sabe tentar DOMDocument ou XPath seja melhor.

Comment: tentei `utf8_decode` e `encode` no resultado de `file_ge_contents` porém sem sucesso, os caracteres continuam "embaralhados"

Comment: Você já tentou alterar a primeira linha do XML para ficar : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: @jlHertel realmente ele teria que alterar a 1a linha e mudar o encoding também (com utf8_encode), é que eu deletei os comentários pra não ficar muita coisa aqui, mas ja tinha verificado que o encoding original é ISO-8859-1 (não só pela declaração do topo, vi pelos bytes retornados mesmo pra ter certeza que não estava conflitante). Na verdade, eu não tive problema em ler esse XML em outras linguagens, é um problema mais especifico da situação do autor mesmo.

Comment: @Bacco, mas abrindo a URL pelo navegador, mesmo com a declaração de ISO-8859-1, apresenta caracteres inválidos, ou seja, o navegador consegue ler, mas vê que o encoding está incorreto. Oque eu estou querendo dizer, é que provavelmente a função que você usou em outra linguagem ignora essa problema de caracteres, enquanto a função do PHP ao encontrar isso, está retornando false. Consegue confirmar se em outra linguagem os caracteres aparecem corretamente?

Comment: O que você ve na tela do browser é o encoding que o browser entende. Como esta página não tem um cabeçalho dizendo encoding (não confundir com a declaração do XML) seu browser está tentando mostrar em UTF-8 (afinal, não tem cabeçalho HTTP dizendo que é ISO). Agora, um parser XML não deveria levar em consideração o cabeçalho HTTP ao importar o arquivo, e sim a declaração. Lendo o arquivo original e exibindo como ISO-8859-1 os caracteres estão perfeitos. O problema não é o encoding, e sim o modo de fazer o diagnóstico.

Comment: @jlHertel veja a página sendo exibida em ANSI - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m1hX.png - E exibindo esse XML numa aplicação desktop, está tudo normal também. O fato é que o melhor teste de encoding é baixar os dados e exibir em hexadecimal, por exemplo em um editor como HxD, assim não depende de erros na tela. Olhando os dados binários não tem como errar o diagnóstico. Saída na tela confunde, pois o erro pode ser de exibição apenas. (PS: Testei tudo isso quando a pergunta foi feita também, sem problemas).

Comment: @Bacco, Neste caso, removendo a linha que define o charset deveria ser possível ler o XML. Ou caso apresente erro ainda, ele poderia definir a linha do charset como sendo ANSI mesmo.

Comment: @jlHertel me dá a impressão que o loader que ele está usando (simplexml) só entende UTF-8, por isso a conversão + sua solução de trocar a string deveria resolver. Por curiosidade, segue um Hex Dump do começo da página, com todos os cabeçalhos inclusive:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qowu2.png - Dá pra ver o encoding mais claramente. (isso foi baixado diretamente via HTTP, e salvo no HD só pra facilitar, sem nenhum filtro, usando socket puro, ou seja, nada de conversão do lado do cliente)

Comment: @jlHertel acredito que "trocar" a primeira linha não seria o caso porque quando recebo os dados da requisição ele já vêm com os caracteres embaralhados.
aceito sugestões de outras classes/funções para usar também, não fiquemos preso apenas nessa função em especifico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que o servidor está sempre forçando a compressão dos dados, deixando o dado plano apenas quando o cliente mostra não ter suporte a isso.

Você pode dizer ao servidor que não suporta compressão dos dados e receber o XML. O seguinte código faz isto:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

$curl = curl_init('http://www.cinemark.com.br/programacao.xml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

/* Esta Opção que resolve o problema */
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

$conteudo = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($conteudo);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($conteudo);

var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: isso resolve! obrigado. Qual classe/função você indicaria para tratar XML? estou usando este `simplexml_` mas parece que estou escrevendo muita coisa e sinto que existe algo que simplifique isso!